# Convert a feature collection to image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I have created a feature collection of burned area in the Amazon according to 1-degree grid cells over 20 years. Here is a link to the collection - https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/stavo/FCburn

In this collection, features are the grid cells, columns names are dates.

In order to create a time-lapse video, I would like to create an image collection where each image is a representation of all features and 1 column(month).

I manage to create the wanted image for 1 month with the following code:

```
var Jan2015 = FCburn.select('2005_01_01_BurnDate')
                    .reduceToImage(['2005_01_01_BurnDate'], ee.Reducer.first())
                    .clip(borderB)
```

However, I can't manage to figure out how I would iterate through each column in the collection to create an image collection. I could not find an example of a function that iterates through columns rather than features in a feature collection. 
How would you go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the code below could help:

```
var properties = FCburn.first().propertyNames().sort().slice(0, -3)
var col = ee.ImageCollection(properties.map(function(property) {
  return FCburn.select([property])
    .reduceToImage([property], ee.Reducer.first())
    .clip(borderB)
    .set('Date', ee.Date(ee.String(property).slice(0, 10).replace('_', '-', 'g')))
 }))
```

The first line is to get all properties (columns) of every feature in `FCburn`. `sort` and  `slice` methods are used to make sure the list does not include unwanted columns (`ID`, `burnAreaProp`, and `system:index`).

The rest of the code is to create an image collection according to what you described in your question.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I can't say I understand exactly what the function is doing, but it works! Only thing is, I would like to preserve the property name in the image collection, so I would know what date the image is from. Right now I can only see Image 1 Image to etc.

Comment: @Stavo, I added one more line to set a `Date` attributes for each image. You may want to set `system:time_start` attribute (the default time attribute in GEE) instead of `Date`.

Comment: As far as I know, we cannot set a name for an image. But this does not mean there's no way to distinguish them. We can easily set any attribute to an image, like I set `Date` attribute in the example code. Then you can filter the image of interest from image collection using `filterMetadata`.

Comment: I was thinking to preserve the date so I could later add it to each layer of the gif. However, using the .getVideoThumbURL I can not generate a decent gif, due to the size of the image collection and the size of the region. Thank you for your help anyway!